# FancyBox iFrame Not Loading On IE & Firefox

Tags: jquery, iframe, fancybox

Trying to load fancybox with an iframe version of my desktop site at mobile and tablet dimensions for my CV website.

On Chrome I have had no issues, however IE and Firefox do not like it for some reason. There are no entries in the console, it just will not load. **This only occcurs on the index page. Works fine on other pages**

I changed the href to an image location and this loaded without a hitch.

Please help!

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".mobile").fancybox({
    type    : 'iframe',
            beforeLoad : function() {         
            this.width  = parseInt(this.element.data('fancybox-width'));  
            this.maxHeight = parseInt(this.element.data('fancybox-height'));
    }
  });
 });
```

HTML

```
<ul class="dropdown">
<li><a class="mobile fancybox.iframe" data-fancybox-width="768" data-fancybox-height="1024" data-fancybox-href="/"> <p> Tablet</p></a></li>
<li><a class="mobile fancybox.iframe" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="/" data-fancybox-width="320" data-fancybox-height="568"> <p> Mobile</p> </a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

FIXED
Just added '?iframe' after the href

Comment: My guess? you were using fancybox v1.x with code for fancybox v2.x